# Prevent click event of plotOutput getting reset when using a module

Tags: r, shiny

For my `shiny` application I use a module with a variant number of inputs. In my main application I want now to create an interactive plot. I added a `click` event (`click = "onClick"`) handler to the `plotOutput`. When I click on a point, `input$onClick` gets updated, but becomes `NULL` right afterwards.

You can try it out in the application: if you click on a point in the left graph, the values of `input$onClick` are printed, but become `NULL` right afterwards.

This has to have something to do with the module, becasue if you click on a point in the right graph the information is persistent.

So it seems that there is some sort of communication between `client` and `server` which invalidates `input$onclick` when using modules. Anything I could do about it?

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

testUI <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   uiOutput(ns("placeholder"))
}

test <- function(input, output, session, n) {
    output$placeholder <- renderUI({
        do.call(tagList, llply(1:n(), function(i)
                   numericInput(session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), 
                session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), sample(0:100, 1), 0, 100)))
    })
    getData <- reactive(unlist(reactiveValuesToList(input)[1:n()]))
    list(getData = getData)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    flowLayout(
        numericInput("n", "Number of Elements", 3, 1, 10),
        testUI("x"),
        testUI("y")),
    flowLayout(
        plotOutput("plot", click = "onClick"),
        plotOutput("plot2", click = "onClick2")),
    verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    getN <- reactive(input$n)
    handler <- list(x = callModule(test, "x", getN),
                    y = callModule(test, "y", getN))
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(handler$x$getData(), handler$y$getData())
        dat <- data.frame(x = handler$x$getData(),
                          y = handler$y$getData())
        qplot(x, y, data = dat)})
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(qplot(mpg, cyl, data = mtcars))
    output$debug <- renderPrint(list(input$onClick, input$onClick2))
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the server, in a trial to track the issue. First, I will highlight what I suspect to be the issue, Then I will write an alternative solution.

**First: Possible Issues**

I think `output$plot` is rendered twice, if you put `print("here")` inside `output$plot <- renderPlot({})` , you'll see that with each click, it gets executed twice.

Probably, it gets invalidated twice. I suspect that **the issue might be related to using** `getData <- reactive(unlist(reactiveValuesToList(input)[1:n()]))`. Because when I replaced it with an alternative reactive expression `getData <- reactive(1:n())` , it worked properly.

I think, when one clicks on the plot:

- `input` changes (because it includes `input$onClick`)

[image]

- `getData <- reactive(unlist(reactiveValuesToList(input)[1:n()]))` gets invalidated
- the plot object for `output$plot` gets invalidated because it depends on the previous values.
- `input` reads the current value of `onClick` which is `NULL`

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

testUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  uiOutput(ns("placeholder"))
}

test <- function(input, output, session, n) {

  output$placeholder <- renderUI({
    do.call(tagList,
            llply(1:n(), function(i)
              numericInput(session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), 
                           session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), sample(0:100, 1), 0, 100)))
  })

  getData <- reactive(unlist(reactiveValuesToList(input)[1:n()]))

  ## TEST: this will work ----------
  # getData <- reactive(1:n())  

  list(getData = getData)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  flowLayout(
    numericInput("n", "Number of Elements", 3, 1, 10),
    testUI("x"),
    testUI("y")),
  flowLayout(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "onClick"),
    plotOutput("plot2", click = "onClick2")),
  verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  # handler <- list(x = callModule(test, "x", getN),
  #                 y = callModule(test, "y", getN))
  # 
  # output$plot <- renderPlot({
  #   req(handler$x$getData(), handler$y$getData())
  #   dat <- data.frame(x = handler$x$getData(),
  #                     y = handler$y$getData())
  #   qplot(x, y, data = dat)})


  getN <- reactive(input$n)

  ## call modules -------------------
  xx <- callModule(test, "x", getN)
  yy <- callModule(test, "y", getN)

  ## data to be plotted in left plot
  dat <- reactive({
    data.frame(x = xx$getData(),
               y = yy$getData())
  })

  ## left plot ------------------
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(xx$getData(),yy$getData())
    print("here")
    qplot(x, y, data = dat())
  })

  ## right plot ------------------
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    qplot(mpg, cyl, data = mtcars)
  })

  output$debug <- renderPrint(c(input$onClick$x,input$onClick2$y))
  # output$debug <- renderPrint(dat())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Second: Alternative Solution**

In this alternative solutions:

- `test` will return nothing
- get the coordinates of the numericInput fields in `x_coord()` & `y_coord()` *(There might be other ways to achieve this)*.
- form the dataframe `dat()`.
- `req()` condition was roughly chosen, but could be anything to achieve the desired result.

---

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

testUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  uiOutput(ns("placeholder"))
}

test <- function(input, output, session, n) {

  output$placeholder <- renderUI({
    do.call(tagList,
            llply(1:n(), function(i)
              numericInput(session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), 
                           session$ns(paste("n", i, sep = ".")), sample(0:100, 1), 0, 100)))
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  flowLayout(
    numericInput("n", "Number of Elements", 3, 1, 10),
    testUI("x"),
    testUI("y")),
  verbatimTextOutput("debug"),
  flowLayout(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "onClick"),
    plotOutput("plot2", click = "onClick2"))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  getN <- reactive(input$n)

   ## call modules -------------------
   callModule(test, "x", getN)
   callModule(test, "y", getN)


   ## get coordinates fromnumeric inputs ----------
   x_coord <- reactive(sapply((1:input$n),function(x) input[[paste0("x-n.",x)]]))
   y_coord <- reactive(sapply((1:input$n),function(x) input[[paste0("y-n.",x)]]))

   ## create data frame
   dat <- reactive({
     req(input[[paste0("y-n.",input$n)]]) # could be changed 
     data.frame(x = x_coord(),
                y = y_coord())
   })

  ## render left plot ------------------
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input[[paste0("y-n.",input$n)]]) # could be changed 
    qplot(x, y, data = dat())
  })

  ## render right plot ------------------
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    qplot(mpg, cyl, data = mtcars)
  })

  ## cat coordinates of clicked points ---------------
  output$debug <- renderPrint(c(input$onClick$x,input$onClick$y))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! It enlightened me and I could solve the problem. FYI: I changed `getData` and got rid of `reactiveValuesToList` which - as you pointed out - was causing this issue. My `getData` looks now like this: `getData <- reactive({
      res <- vector("numeric", n());
      nams <- paste("n", 1:n(), sep = ".");
      ## have to use this workaround as single bracketing '[' does not work with 'input'
      for (i in seq_along(nams)) {
         n <- nams[[i]];
         res[[i]] <- input[[n]];
      }
      res})`

Comment: @thothal glad it helped. One of the things I used to trace the behavior of the reactive values is [Reactive Log Visualizer](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/showReactLog.html). It could help sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use that but not sure whether I totally understand its output. Do you have any tutorial on that at hand? (besides in my real application I have to many dependencies so it starts to be quite messy) +1  in any case :)

Comment: @thothal I think if one understands the flow as explained in [Execution scheduling](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html) and [How to understand reactivity in R](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html), it'd be easier to grasp the output of the Reactive Log Visualizer.